# Window functions with summations on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

What I'm trying to achieve is to calculate a daily, weekly and monthly leaderboard with `sum(points)`, all-time high points and all-time low points per user (and per time-frame) but haven't had a lot of success. My schema look like:

```
CREATE TABLE users( 
  id   SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY,
  name text    NOT NULL
);

-- contains millions of rows!
CREATE TABLE results( 
  id      SERIAL      PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id integer     NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
  points  float       NOT NULL, -- can be negative
  date    timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);

-- sample data
INSERT INTO users (name)
VALUES ('user1'), ('user2'), ('user3'), ('user4');

INSERT INTO results (user_id, points)
VALUES (2, -10), (1, 50), (4, -20), (3, 20), (2, 50), (4, -20), (1, 50), (1, -25), (4, 30), (3, -70), (2, 50), (1, -25), (4, 20), (2, -90), (3, 60), (4, -20);
```

so for example, assuming those results where correspond to the last week, the weekly leaderboard would have something like:

```
User|sum(points)  User|ATH points  User|ATL points
1    50           1    100         3    -50
3    10           2    90          4    -40
```

which are only calculated with the results where `date` is in the last week, and so on.

but in order to achieve that it seems to me that I need to somehow iterate over every bet to calculate the highest and the lowest amounts of points the user had at any point in that time-frame. Doing it in-memory isn't going to work well, because I'll need to store millions of results in memory.

Is there anyway of doing it completely in a query?. I've looked into window functions but don't see how a summation could be done using them.

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just added some. It produces the results I showed.

Comment: Use common SUM for `sum(points)` and SUM with FILTER for another two columns. I'd recommend 3 separate CTEs with ordering and limitation - each by separate summary field with additional ROW_NUMBER(),- and JOIN them by row number in main query.

Comment: *just added some* This is not useful. Post it as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. And example output MUST match shown example data fully! whereas now the "ATL points" champions are users 1 and 3 which have -50 negative score each.

Comment: The question is unclear: How is that "all times high" and "all times low" calculated? It is not the minimum value.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe no. It is calculated by iterating over every result and summing the points. Then in every iteration, if the new sum is higher than the current ATH, then that's the new ATH.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but a foreign key column referencing a `serial` should **not** be declared as serial but as `integer`. [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) serial isn't a real data type and with modern Postgres an `identity` column is the preferred way to get an "auto increment"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh cool, thanks for that

Comment: @hoanmar Iteration in which order?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe ordered by date. So for user1 we'd first have an ATH of 50 and then it goes up to 100. Since his other bets are negative 100 is the final ATH.

Comment: Does "all time" mean "all time in the last week"?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes. It means "the highest amount of points the user had at any point in the last week" and "the lowest amount of points..".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use window functions to calculate the sum and the running sum (ordered by `date`), then take the minimum and maximum of the running sums:

```
SELECT user_id,
       sum,
       min(running) AS atl,
       max(running) AS ath
FROM (SELECT user_id,
             sum(points) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id),
             sum(points) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date) AS running
      FROM results
      WHERE date > current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 week') AS q
GROUP BY user_id, sum;
```

Comment: Thank you!. But sum, min and max produce exactly the same value (the sum) as it is.

Comment: That's because all the dates in your example are the same. You have to improve your example.